# Installing Google Appengine on Windows 7

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

My Windows Vista Laptop is dying so I purchased a new HP Laptop running Windows 7 Pro 64 Bit.
I then downloaded and installed python-2.7.8.amd64.msi. Followed by GoogleAppEngine-1.9.9.
Copied my Google App Application from the Vista Laptop to the Win7 and tried to run it.  The problem is that more often than not Chrome just displays a blank page and the App Launcher Log shows a mammoth entry, shown below.  Refreshing the Chrome screen sometimes displays the page correctly, sometimes it takes 3 or 4 attempts.  (Note that this problem is across a couple of projects and all .html screens within them)
So, my question: any thoughts on what I have done wrong here?  
The log reads ... 
INFO     2014-08-22 11:25:40,788 module.py:642] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2014-08-22 11:25:41,354 module.py:642] default: "GET /mainmenu.html HTTP/1.1" 200 8366
INFO     2014-08-22 11:25:41,367 module.py:642] default: "GET /static/fsnormal.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2014-08-22 11:25:41,374 module.py:642] default: "GET /static/fsprint.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2014-08-22 11:25:41,375 module.py:642] default: "GET /static/fsscript.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2014-08-22 11:25:41,375 module.py:642] default: "GET /static/appengine-noborder.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2014-08-22 11:25:41,421 module.py:642] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 8364
IncompleteRead(2 bytes read)

IncompleteRead(2 bytes read)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate

```
req.respond()
```

[ 100 lines removed ]

File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 543, in read

```
return self._read_chunked(amt)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 597, in _read_chunked

```
raise IncompleteRead(''.join(value))
```

IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(2 bytes read)

INFO     2014-08-22 11:26:28,727 module.py:642] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 8364

Answer (score 0):

Out of frustration I updated to Windows 8 (came on cd with new laptop) and then 8.1.
Problem seems to have gone.
David